# NPE when attempting to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android

I get

> `java.lang.NullPointerException`: Attempt to invoke virtual method '`void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(android.view.View)`' on a `null` object reference

Here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    f1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
    f1.addView(new myview(getApplicationContext()));
    animation= 
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.translation);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            f1.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

The error is shown in line `f1.addView(new myview(getApplicationContext()));`. I have created an animation program in which i want to call other class into the framelayout that is mention in the code so when i run this then runtime error is showing which is shown below.

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
    at com.cenet.animationclass.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a layout to your activity first:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    f1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
}
```

Comment: ohh, silly mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You did not inflated your layout and you are finding views inside it. This was wrong in your code.

When you wrote `f1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);` then it returned null so `f1` was `null`. Now when you tried to use `f1.addView` then you tried to call addView method of null object so you got `NullPointerException`.

Solution is to create activity layout first by adding `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);` after `super` in `onCreate` like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    f1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
}
```

**Caution** check `frame_layout` is present in your `xml layout`

Comment: ohh, silly mistake. Thank you

Comment: You can mark right to appreciate me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot to add setContent(R.layout.(xmlfile)). Thats why the run time error shows.Hence when ever you inflate your file you must add setContent(R.layout.(xmlfile)).